# Set Range with variable Rownumber

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set a Range. The value 10 is not fix and written in cell D1.
How can i modify

```
Range("A1:A10,C1:C10")
```

to get the Range i want.

I tried

```
Range("A1:A" & Range("D1") & , "C1:C" & Range("D1"))
```

but get the error "method range of object _global failed".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually best to keep your code clean:

```
Dim lastRow
Dim variableRange as Range

lastRow = Range("D1").Value

Set variableRange = Range("A1:A" & lastRow & ", C1:C" & lastRow)
```

Most likely your problem was in the `& ,` bit... The comma needed to be inside the quotation marks.

Note that by creating a separate variable `lastRow`, it is immediately obvious to anyone reading the code what it is doing - the variable name becomes "micro documentation".

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
Range("A1:A" & Range("D1") & ", C1:C" & Range("D1"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have it even less confusing than Floris' solution (which already improved readability), you may try this:

```
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim variablerange As Range
lastrow = Cells(1, 4)

Set variablerange = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, 3))
```